# PHP Codeigniter simple queries show results of count

Tags: codeigniter

Using codeigniter, looking for some help with the controller, model , and view to show counts from a db.
My db table is alertstbl
I want to just count rows where active=1 and show the value
then another count where active=0 and show the value

I have tried this with no luck.

in Model

```
function getCount()
{
    $this->db->select('count(*)');
    $this->db->from('alertstbl');
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get();  

    return $data;
}
```

in Controller

```
   public function getalertcnt(){
    $this->load->model('AlertModel');
    $data = $this->AlertModel->getalertcnt();

    $this->load->view('getCount', $data);
    }
```

in View

```
<div class="row">
   <?php
 foreach($sql->result_array() as $row)
    {
        echo $row['getalertcnt'];
    }
    ?>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

I know I am wayy off base here, its just erroring.
Can someone help me just show some basic count query results.
Thank you

errors on screen from controller and model

Comment: Correct answer placed below....

Answer (score 0):

**Below assumes "active" is either 0 or 1.**

> **ALLWAYS a good idea to keep sql OUT OF the View :)**

Since you're scanning the entire table, you might as well get both:

```sql
SELECT
    `active` AS active,
    COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM
    `alertstbl`
GROUP BY active
```

Which will return: (did this on my users table just now)

```
 ------------------
| active |  count  |
 ------------------
|  0     |  21     |
|  1     |  347723 |
 ------------------
```

**In your Model:**

```php
    //---------------------------------------------------
    // get all Alert Counts
    public function getCount() 
    { 
        $this->db->select('active AS active, COUNT(*) AS count');
        $this->db->from('alertstbl');
        $this->db->group_by('active');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        // the below line will return both [0] and [1] as arrays like above
        $result = $query->result_array();
        
        //return $result;

        // this line will return a single value for Active or InActive using 0 or 1
        // return $result[0]['count']; // returns InActive since 0 is first
        // 
        // my preference is to put it in an array and use what I need
        // lets define an array for the $result
        return array(
            'Active'   => $result[1]['count'],
            'InActive' => $result[0]['count']
        );
    }
```

**In your Controller:**
It should look like this: (or maybe make it a Helper Function?)

```php
public function getalertcnt(){
   $data['alerts'] = $this->AlertModel->getCount();
   $this->load->view('getCount', $data);
}
```

And finally, in your View...

```php
<p>Active alerts: <?= $alerts['Active']; ?></p>
<p>InActive alerts: <?= $alerts['InActive']; ?></p>
```

If you want a helper function, let me know and I will add that here as well. You can then call something directly from the view like:

```php
// get InActive Alerts
<?php echo getAlerts(0); ?>
  
or
  
// get Active Alerts
<?php echo getAlerts(1); ?>
```

Comment: I would suggest adding an `order_by` to the query, since you can't be sure in what order the database will return the 2 rows if no `ORDER BY` clause is specified.

Comment: Hi @Marleen - GROUP BY has explicit sorting by default (which allows ASC or DESC)  UNLESS you are using MySQL 8.0.13+ Then you will need to add `$this->db->order_by('active');` You can find the details here: [MySQL Link](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/removal-of-implicit-and-explicit-sorting-for-group-by/)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are calling the wrong function in your Controller (it should be $this->AlertModel->getCount()) on line 3.

Here is the correct way to do it.

In Model

```
public function getCount ($active=0) { 
   $this->db->select('count(*) AS count');
   $this->db->from('alertstbl');
   $this->db->where('active', $active);
   $sql = $this->db->get();  
   $count = $sql->row_array ();
   return $count;
}
```

In Controller

```
public function getalertcnt(){
   $this->load->model('AlertModel');
   $data['activeRows'] = $this->AlertModel->getCount(1);
   $data['inActiveRows'] = $this->AlertModel->getCount(0);

   $this->load->view('getCount', $data);
}
```

In View

```
<div class="row">
  Active: <?php echo $activeRows['count']; ?>    <br>
  InActive: <?php echo $inActiveRows['count']; ?>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: Your `getCount` method always returns 1: `$this->db->select('count(*)');` always returns exactly 1 row because of the aggregate function, so if you then use `$sql->num_rows();` to count the number of rows, this will always return 1. You need to either leave out the `$this->db->select('count(*)');` line, or keep that line and use `$count = $sql->row()->{'count(*)'};` instead of `$count = $sql->num_rows();`.

Comment: I tried both ways, It just returns NULL for both

Comment: @AsifAziz You are counting twice? @Marleen Incorrect, it will always return NULL as it is not referenceable. Actually @AsifAziz, You have a few mistakes. First, you have to name the count otherwise its difficult to reference "count(*)"  Second, You are already using the DB to perform the work, why double it? If you replace `$this->db->select('count(*)');` with `$this->db->select('count(*)' AS count);` and then replace `$count = $sql->num_rows ();` with `$count = $query->row_array();` you would get a proper result usable in the controller method you posted.

Comment: @DeanE10 You are right. I have corrected my mistakes as pointed out by you. Thanks